# How to stop a Python program when it reaches a certain point?

Tags: python

I want to create a function so that it will find the integer a so that `a <= n`.

If `n` is `99`, then the program will return `a = 3`.
This is because the function is finding the sums of the consecutive cubes.
So, `1 + 8 + 27 + 64 = 100`, which is *more* than `99`. But `1 + 8 + 27` is *less* than `99`, so `a = 3` is the correct answer.

I was trying to do something like:

```
cubes = 0
for i in xrange(1, 1+x)
     cubes += i*i*i
while cubes <= n
```

but I am very confused. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 6):

First replace the `for` loop with a `while` loop:

```
cubes, i = 0, 0
while cubes <= n:
    i += 1
    cubes += i ** 3
```

Then, after the loop, subtract the last cube because you'll have gone over the limit `n`:

```
cubes -= i ** 3
```

`i` still has the final value it had in the loop.

Alternatively, you can do everything in one loop, by first computing the new value of `cubes` as a temporary variable, then only updating `cubes` if you've not gone over the limit:

```
cubes, i = 0, 0
while True:    # infinite loop
    i += 1
    new_cubes = cubes + i ** 3
    if new_cubes > n:
        break
    else:
        cubes = new_cubes
```

Comment: `cubes, i = 0` probably needs replacing with `cubes = 0; i = 0`

Comment: @cdarke: actually what I meant was `cubes, i = 0, 0`. Updated, thanks.

Comment: I'd still probably change it up to @cdarke's suggestion. It's apparent that the OP is new to Python (possibly programming in general), and the way you have it is a confusing construct for a novice programmer. Might make it a bit more readable.

Comment: @KenB alternatively, some parentheses would have made it more readable (although they are not needed).

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) and a for-loop:

```
from itertools import count
def solve(n, pow):
    total = 0
    for i in count(1):
        if total + i**pow > n:
            return i-1
        total += i**pow
```

**Demo**:

```
>>> solve(99, 3)
3
>>> solve(50, 2)
4
```

Comment: Works nicely but perhaps confusing to call your power `a` when it is unrelated to the OP's `a`. Since the OP is apparently just starting out, maybe explain `count(1)`?

Comment: @beroe I've linked it with docs. Fixed the variable related confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
def cubes(n=1):
  while True:
    yield n ** 3
    n += 1

def sum(array):
  total = 0
  for item in array:
    total += item
    yield total

def sum_cubes_lt(n):
  for i, sum in enumerate(sum(cubes()):
    if sum > n:
      return i

# prints '3'
print sum_cubes_lt(99)
```